# Explanation of Information double summation within Normalized Mutual Information

Tags: information-theory, clustering

The Normalized Mutual Information NMI calculation is described in deflation-PIC paper with the applicable formula copied to the screenshot shown below.

My question is specifically about the *double* summation of the numerator: why is it a double summation. My (apparently incorrect) intuition would be that the numerator would contain all of the elements that are common between the X and Y - as represented by the "L" and "H" summations in the formula.  Then the common elements could be represented by a single summation over either one of the random variables (X or Y) and that filters for the *corresponding* member of the other cluster to have the same membership value (i.e. cluster).  Instead the *double* summation is where I can use assistance for what that achieves.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is rather sloppy... First, it's $I(X;Y)$ , not $I(X,Y)$ (the notation is important). Second, "the mutual information between $X$ and itself is 1" made me quiver, until I understood that it actually meant "the normalized mutual information". Third, the factors inside the square root lack a minus sign - (yes, they cancel in the multiplication, but it's slightly confusing/ugly)

Regarding the numerator: the [mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Relation_to_other_quantities), in terms of the probabilities functions, is

$$I(X;Y)= \sum_{x,y}p_{X,Y}(x,y)\log \frac{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}{p_X(x) p_Y(y)} $$

Mapping $p_X(x) \to n_{\ell}/n $,  $p_Y(y) \to n_{h}/n $ , $p_{X,Y}(x,y) \to n_{\ell,h}/n $ you get

$$I(X;Y) =\sum_{\ell,h} \frac{n_{\ell,h}}{n} \log \frac{n_{\ell,h} \, n}{n_{h} \, n_{\ell}}  $$

So, ugly notations aside, it's right. The missing $1/n$ was cancelled with the same factor in the denominator of the complete NMI expression.